# Using HTML5 Boolean Data Attributes in an XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

When trying to use Boolean Data Attributes (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) in my Xpage I get syntax errors.

The markup snippet:

```
<label>
    <span>Layout</span>
    <select class="layout-option m-wrap small">
        <option value="fluid" selected>Fluid</option>
        <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Causes the following parse error:

> Attribute name "selected" associated with an element type "option" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

I have set the doctype to HTML5.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't think XPage would allow you to use boolean attributes. The link in your question itself suggests that you can write you code like this `<option value="fluid" selected="selected">Fluid</option>` and it would work in XPages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification to Sven's answer did the trick:

```
<label>
    <span>Layout</span>
    <select class="layout-option m-wrap small">
        <xp:text escape="true" tagName="option" value="Fluid">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="value" value="fluid" />
                <xp:attr name="selected" minimized="true" value="" />
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:text>
        <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Generates the HTML:

```
<label>
    <span>Layout</span>
    <select class="layout-option m-wrap small">
        <option value="fluid" selected>Fluid</option>
        <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when using a computed text and the *minimized* option in the attributes.

```
<label>
    <span>Layout</span>
       <select class="layout-option m-wrap small">
        <xp:text escape="true" tagName="option" styleClass="" value="Fluid">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="selected" minimized="true" value="" />
            </xp:this.attrs>
       </xp:text>

        <option value="boxed">Boxed</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPages source must be XML compliant, so HTML5 does not fit. You have few options.

1. Use any value in property, as suggested by Naveen.
2. Use custom rendered attribute as suggested by Sven.
3. Output HTML5 by [computedText](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/How_to_Simulate_Pass-Thru_HTML_on_an_XPage) control.
4. Make your own [component](http://www.intec.co.uk/html-or-xpage-component/) (OSGi, in database) that outputs SELECT tag to your liking.